# Depending on the result of two input, define the result of a third input readonly with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two inputs `ID_1` and `ID_2` of selection and I would like to see a result in a third read-only input `Result`

Examples:

```
ID_1 = 1 and ID_2 = 1 then RESULT = "Correct" 
ID_2 = 1 and ID_1 = 2 then RESULT = "Fail" 
ID_1 = 1 and ID_2 = 2 then RESULT = "Fail" 
ID_1 = 2 and ID_2 = 2 then RESULT = "Fail"
```

Hello community

I need help with the following. I currently have the following HTML code consisting of two selection entries

What I need is a javascript script that validates the results of the two entries (ID_1) and (ID_2) according to the selection to give a result in the entry (Result)

The comparison logic should be the following:

```
ID_1 = 1 and ID_2 = 1 then Result = "Aproved"
ID_1 = 1 and ID_2 = 2 then Result = "Fail"
ID_2 = 1 and ID_1 = 2 then Result = "Error"
```

I remain attentive to your comments.

I tried to create a part of the code but I do not know how to continue, please help

```js
//<script language="javascript">
function validation()
   var Sino_1 = document.form.ID_1.value;
   var Sino_2 = document.form.ID_2.value;

   if (ID_1 = 1 && ID_2 = 1)

//</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Validation report</title>
  </head>
<body>
<fieldset>
<footer>
 <form id=form>

<h2 class="encabezados" align="center">Validation report</h2>

Question 1?<br><select name="ID_1" id="ID_1" required>
     <option value="0">Select</option>
   <option value="1">Yes</option>
   <option value="2">Not</option>
</select>

<br><br>Question 1<br><select name="ID_2" id="ID_2" required>
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="2">Not</option>
</select>
<br><br><button onclick="Validation" class="button" align="center" type="submit">Validation</button>

<br><br>Result<input type="text" name="Result" id="Result" readonly>
</form>
</footer>
</fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dear, please help me with the following I have two input (ID_1) and (ID_2) of selecction and I would like to see a result in a third read-only input (Result)

Example

ID_1 = 1 and ID_2 = 1 then RESULT = "Correct"
ID_2 = 1 and ID_1 = 2 then RESULT = "Fail"
ID_1 = 1 and ID_2 = 2 then RESULT = "Fail"
ID_1 = 2 and ID_2 = 2 then RESULT = "Fail"

Comment: Hi Juan and welcome to StackOverflow. I placed your comment as your question. For future reference, you can edit your own post by clicking `Edit` to the lower left of the question. While we are a welcoming community, most users are English speakers and you'll be more likely to receive help by keeping it in English. Also, you'll likely receive downvotes unless you show an attempt. Include any HTML code you've written, and your attempted Javascript code too. Few people will write a solution for you from scratch.

Comment: Removed question-text from code formatting and inserted given trial code into snippet format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your html as well as in javascript code.
Please check the below code, I have mentioned the mistakes in code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Validation report</title>

    <body>
        <fieldset>
            <footer>
                <form id=form>

                    <h2 class="encabezados" align="center">Validation report</h2>

                    Question 1?
                    <br>
                    <select name="ID_1" id="ID_1" required>
                        <option value="0">Select</option>
                        <option value="1">Yes</option>
                        <option value="2">Not</option>
                    </select>

                    <br>
                    <br>Question 1
                    <br>
                    <select name="ID_2" id="ID_2" required>
                        <option value="0">Select</option>
                        <option value="1">Yes</option>
                        <option value="2">Not</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                     <!-- wrong function name validation -->
                     <!-- type="submit" TO type="button"--> 
                    <button onclick="validation()" class="button" align="center" type="button">Validation</button>

                    <br>
                    <br>Result
                    <input type="text" name="Result" id="Result" readonly>
                </form>
            </footer>
        </fieldset>
</head>
</body>

<script language="javascript">

    // missing function brackets {}
    function validation() {
        // use getElementById to get value
        var Sino_1 = document.getElementById('ID_1').value;
        var Sino_2 = document.getElementById('ID_2').value;
        // var Sino_1 = document.form.ID_1.value;
        // var Sino_2 = document.form.ID_2.value;

        /// = TO ==
        // AND user Sino_1 , Sino_2
        if (Sino_1 == 1 && Sino_2 == 1) {
            document.getElementById('Result').value = 'Aproved';
        }
        else if (Sino_1 == 1 && Sino_2 == 2) {
            document.getElementById('Result').value = 'Fail';
        }
        else if (Sino_1 == 2 && Sino_2 == 1) {
            document.getElementById('Result').value = 'Error';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('Result').value = '';
        }
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great contribution, this resolves my requirement.

Comment: That's great. Thanks for approving and up voting the answer.